# Pagination approach recommendation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, pagination

I need to implement pagination in my Spring MVC / JSP / Hibernate (annotation based) application, I've read about

1. PagedListHolder
2. Display tag library
3. Hibernate pagination

So I was wondering which is the best pagination approach experienced developers recommend in term of

1. Easiness of implementation
2. Flexibility

What I need to have at the end is a pagination approach that will allow me to have (First - 1 - 2 - 3 -4 - 5....Last) as pagination bar, where the page numbers 1,2,3,4,5 are dynamically changed based on currently displayed page.

Thanks for your time

Comment: http://datatables.net/

Comment: @GriffeyDog Datatables are like JQGrid, I know this approach but I prefer that with pagination on html tables. Thanks though for your help

Comment: No, Datatables works directly with HTML tables. It has many options for how data is retrieved and paginated.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Thanks a lot for the clarification, I can see now that it works directly with HTML tables but I see it has a major con which is that it doesn't work good with tables that contains huge number of records, which will require (if I use it) to pass current position and page size to server and get data from database batch by batch. So I was wondering do you how do you handle big data? batch by batch also?

Comment: Yeah, for large sets of data I use the server-side processing option. It works well, but it does require more work.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Please post your reply as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables](http://datatables.net/) offers most, if not all of the features you need, and has many options for pagination, sorting, etc. It works directly with HTML tables and can use jQuery/AJAX to retrieve data (paginated) if needed for larger sets of data.